# ngrx - summarize actions to 'processes'

Tags: angular, ngrx

I would like to discuss the idea to summarize actions to 'processes'.

I have a process in my application: (1) select module (2) I also need to reset some stuff and
(3) select other stuff... So I have to execute three actions in a row.

The simple idea is to create a method and put these three 'dispatch action' into this method and call this method wherever I need it.

Is there something similar available in ngrx? What speaks against it?

Comment: you coild Create a 4th action and and an associate effect which would dispatch the 3 other actions, this way you dispatch only one from your controller.

Comment: you could also create route guards to make sure the necessary data is available before the navigation is completed. either way there is usually no scape from dispatching multiple actions when you are dealing with multiple states

Comment: Maybe ngrx facades are applicable?